# Using Wave Modifier instances in Animation node

Tags: animation, modifiers, animation-nodes, text-object, instances

In animation nodes is it possible to take an object data path output and run it with an instancer? 
 I am trying to give a ghost type effect to the wave modifier on text.  Throught the wave of the text, I want to be able to see a slightly invisible version of where its going.

I can do what i want to an object, but the modifiers do not get instanced in animation nodes.

also it looks as if I am instancing it, however that is just the data from the wave modifier, as well as the wave modifier applied to the object. I cant get more than these 2 instances or manipulate the second instance (x,y,z space ect.)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actions in Animation Nodes are abstractions of F-Curves, or possibly other data. So actions are not effective when it comes to animations that depends solely on data such as the current frame in this case.

If I understand what you want to do correctly, you can use the time offset parameter of the wave modifier. So, instance your objects using the *Copy Full Object* option to copy the modifiers from the source object to the instance, and modulate the time offset parameter using an attribute output node as follows:

[image: Node Tree]

### Ghosting Value

What you can do is set the pass index of object to an arithmetic sequence, then in the shader, sample the object's pass index, and divide it by the number of instances as follows:

[image: Node Tree]

Comment: Omar your the man, How would you get these instances into a list, to add colors for each instance? Im trying to go from the object action output to invoke subprogram, but as far as I can tell it will not modify the colors, once it is brought into the shatder with the attribute node.

Comment: Sorry Omar, figured it out, didnt have the viewport on render

Comment: @NickSieben Also, make sure to check *Deep Copy* when editing mesh data such as vertex colors. Moreover, since your colors are merely evenly spaced grey scale values, you can set the *Object Index* of the objects and use the output from the *Object Info* node to color your objects. Let me know if you want me to elaborate on that.

Comment: yes I would appreciate if you could elaborate on that. Thank you

Comment: @NickSieben I elaborated on the coloring method. Feel free to ask a more specific question if you want.

Comment: Omar, Thanks for all the help. Adding this to another question. What I have is now text with this ghost effect.  And I want to use a boolean modifier with a sphere, so the text can grow out of nothing, if that makes any sense. but Once I apply the Boolean modifier It doesn't enable me to use the ghost effect with transparency.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/128688/animation-nodes-and-boolean-modifier