# Animation Nodes and Boolean Modifier

Tags: animation, texturing, modifiers, animation-nodes

Using this setup in animation nodes I created a phantom effect for my text with a wave modifier, but when I apply a boolean modifier it gets rid of the transparency of my text. Is there a way to apply the boolean without effecting the text transparency?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are storing your transparency information in vertex colors layers. Some modifiers—including the boolean modifier—are destructive when it comes to mesh data such as vertex color layers. So upon applying a boolean modifier carrying vertex color data, the data is destroyed.

You have two ways to fix this, you either use another medium to pass the transparency information to cycles, or you dispense the boolean modifier in favour of another approach to achieve the same effect.

## Dispense The Boolean Modifier

A more efficient approach would be to write a shader that changes the transparency of the fragments dynamically. Use the object space texture coordinates of an empty as the vector input of a *Quadratic Sphere Gradient* node and get the fragments that their gradient value is larger than zero. Use the output as a transparency mask and animate the empty location and scale to get the effect you had before:

[image: Node Tree]

Comment: This looks excellent! Do you have any suggestions for material I should read into/ google that would help me understand logic nodes / modifiers / anything else that had come up in the questions you have helped me with?

Comment: @NickSieben Not really. Most of this knowledge is gained by experience. So spend a lot of time trying things around until you get the hang of it. Please accept the answer if it answers your question.

Comment: I will when I can try it tonight. Thank you

Comment: I cant seem to get this working properly, I have it connected to a mix shader, mixing with the transparency node, and I have half a cube visible, but no amount of scale seems to effect it. Im not sure if I have the node connection proper after what you show.

Comment: It could be broken in 2.8, I did get it to work in 2.79b

Comment: It just doesnt work in Eevee, works in cycles 2.8

Comment: @NickSieben Yes. As far as I know, the object texture coordinates is not fully supported in EEVEE.

Comment: is there a way to add a feathered edge to the quadratic sphere? I tried using a diffuse node, but couldnt get it working with that.

Comment: @NickSieben Just replace the *Greater Than* node with a *Color Ramp* node and edit the ramp until you get what you are looking for.